# Is there a way to add styles to a select tag while it is in focus and also has the dropdown in view

Tags: html, css, web, frontend, styling

So, I'm making a page that has a bunch of html and css snippets that i may need in the future and i have successfully customised the `<select>` tag by adding padding, removing default appearance, and putting a custom caret in and i have also added a border radius that is equal to the sum of the top and bottom padding to make the corners completely rounded. My question is, how can I make the `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` equal 0 only while the dropdown is open so they look connected?
HTML:

```
<!-- Don't ask about the languages lol -->
<select name="language" class="select">
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select a language</option>
    <option value="klingon">Klingon</option>
    <option value="sindarin">Sindarin</option>
    <option value="dothraki">Dothraki</option>
    <option value="aramaic">Aramaic</option>
    <option value="latin">Latin</option>
    <option value="akkadian">Akkadian</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```css
.select {
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: var(--text);
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: none;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background-color: var(--bg);
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg aria-hidden='true' focusable='false' data-prefix='fas' data-icon='caret-down' role='img' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 320 512' class='svg-inline--fa fa-caret-down fa-w-10 fa-3x'%3E%3Cpath fill='white' d='M31.3 192h257.3c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L174.1 354.8c-7.8 7.8-20.5 7.8-28.3 0L17.2 226.1C4.6 213.5 13.5 192 31.3 192z' class=''%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
    background-position: right 15px top 50%, 0 0;
    background-size: .65em auto, 100%;
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
}

.select:focus {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

As you can see, I have tried `.select:focus` but it stays in focus after you have selected your option and it looks stupid on its own with square corners on the bottom. I have also tried `.select:hover:focus` which works until your cursor leaves the select element and the style rule no longer applies.

P.S: in dark mode, `--bg` is equal to #222222, `--text` is equal to #FFFFFF
and in light mode, they are equal to #EEEEEE and #000000 respectively.
P.P.S: I have also jus tried `.select:focus:enabled` and that works but again, once i select an option and the dropdown disappears, the styles are still in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to style the dropdown.

But I think there is a way to solve,  this is by writing your own custom dropdown with some JavaScript codes.

You can check here the WHYs: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/

Hope it helps

Comment: I wasn't intending on using javascript but a little bit can't hurt, I'll check it out